# Comma after "that" before parenthetical clause: optional?

Tags: grammar, commas, that, non-restrictive

I've noticed I'm coming across a lot of sentences that look like this, with a parenthetical clause surrounded by commas and preceded by a "that" that functions as a conjunction opening a that-clause:

> It seems coherent to say that, within the framework of Simmons's moral theory, good and bad acts exist along a continuum.

This is all grammatical and that's fine. It would also be correct, if the sentence is simple enough, to omit the commas. But I wonder if it would also be correct to omit just the first comma:

> It seems coherent to say that within the framework of Simmons's moral theory, good and bad acts exist along a continuum.

As far as I can tell, this is far less common, but depending on the complexity of the sentence, I sometimes prefer it. First, it matches the flow of my speech better. Second, more "objectively," it avoids a slight garden-path tendency to read the "that" as a demonstrative pronoun.

Am I just in the wrong here?

Comment: It all depends on where you think the natural pause would be here. Commas are personal, not rule driven usually. [Except for teens learning to write a paragraph. :))

Comment: It's rare that medial parentheticals don't have balanced offsetting punctuation (whether commas, dashes, brackets, or [as you say] where reasonable zero punctuation).  But I agree that your example is hardly impaired by the single parenthetical-ending comma. I'd not feel aggrieved coming across such punctuation (in certain cases like this one), though one has to be wary of less accommodating editors, teachers, tutors ....

Comment: I agree with the above but might prefer to move the parenthetical. Better to put a qualification at the beginning or end, not in the middle to break up the flow.

Comment: What @StuartF said. I think it would be much smoother to *start* with the "scene-setting" parenthetical: *Within the framework of Simmons's moral theory[,] it seems coherent to say [that] good and bad acts exist along a continuum.* It seems to me that either or both the comma *and* the conjunction "that" then become at least potentially discardable - which I take as evidence that the sequence is inherently more "elegant".

Comment: Since said existence along a continuum is strictly within said framework, the clause "within the framework of Simmons's moral theory" cannot be omitted from the given sentences, so isn't really a parenthetical clause, is it? As such, the second example seems more correct than the first. Similarly, "I'd say that in my class, I'm the tallest" is more correct than "I'd say that, in my class, I'm the tallest".

Comment: I would say that the preposition phrase "within the framework of Simmons's moral theory" is sufficiently integrated into the clause so as not to class it as a supplement (your parenthetical). No punctuation at all is required.

Comment: @FumbleFingers — No, putting it at the beginning changes the meaning of the sentence, which is: *It seems coherent to say that **good and bad acts exist along a continuum within the framework of Simmons's moral theory.***

Comment: Comma usage has always been, and remains, a matter of choice.

If your editor or publisher has explicit rules, follow those rules.

Otherwise, write what feels right to you and depending on how much the particular point means to you, be prepared to argue the case with your editor or publisher

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. Very helpful. I'll just say re the mores specific comments that the sentence is merely an example and that I'm interested in the general principle. Many of the real-world examples I had in mind—which unfortunately I couldn't find when I was writing this—were from the Moncrieff/Kilmartin/Andreas Mayor/Enright Proust, which I have not yet found cause to criticise on stylistic grounds!